# Typescript: Is it possible to create a tuple of specified length?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

It should work like:

```
type SpecifiedLengthTuple<T, L extends number> = ???

type tupleOfThreeStrings = SpecifiedLengthTuple<string, 3> // [string, string, string]
```

If someone wonders, I want this to solve this question: [Typescript: increment number type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243431/typescript-increment-number-type)

with the help of `TupleUnshift` type from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53985533/9259778):

by checking `['length']` of a resulted (unshifted) tuple.

Comment: [Not officially](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223).  You can come up with a recursive definition that even compiles using a trick, but in practice the compiler will stop checking properly after some depth (6? 20? something like that) so a hardcoded list like `[[],[any],[any,any],...]` is probably the best you can do right now.

Comment: Hi @jcalz Thank you. Can you please also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243565/typescript-how-to-make-a-recursion) related question? It's about recursion, but I think it would be OK if the limit is 20 or something. At least I want to know how to defeat the recursion (circular references) error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `PrependToTuple` generic with takes tuple `[...T]` and `Item` and returns `[I, ...T]`

```js
type PrependTuple<A, T extends Array<any>> = 
  (((a: A, ...b: T) => void) extends (...a: infer I) => void ? I : [])
```

You can use recursive call that returns tuple when `length` is equals `N` and return accumulated tuple with prepend item if is not equals `N`

```js
type SpecifiedLengthTuple<T, N extends number, L extends Array<any> = []> = {
  true: L;
  false: SpecifiedLengthTuple<T, N, PrependTuple<T, L>>;
}[L['length'] extends N ? "true" : "false"];

type Result = SpecifiedLengthTuple<boolean, 3>; // [boolean, boolean, boolean]
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=type%20PrependTuple%3CA%2C%20T%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%3E%20%3D%20%0D%0A%20%20(((a%3A%20A%2C%20...b%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20extends%20(...a%3A%20infer%20I)%20%3D%3E%20void%20%3F%20I%20%3A%20%5B%5D)%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20SpecifiedLengthTuple%3CT%2C%20N%20extends%20number%2C%20L%20extends%20Array%3Cany%3E%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20true%3A%20L%3B%0D%0A%20%20false%3A%20SpecifiedLengthTuple%3CT%2C%20N%2C%20PrependTuple%3CT%2C%20L%3E%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%5BL%5B'length'%5D%20extends%20N%20%3F%20%22true%22%20%3A%20%22false%22%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Result%20%3D%20SpecifiedLengthTuple%3Cboolean%2C%203%3E%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5Bboolean%2C%20boolean%2C%20boolean%5D)