# Typescript: how to achieve a recursion in this type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, recursive-type

My original problem is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243431/typescript-increment-number-type).

I made the following type but it does not work due to the circular references error and I don't know how to solve it:

```
type Increment<T extends number, Tuple extends any[] = [any]> = 
T extends 0 ? 1 :
T extends 1 ? 2 :
T extends TupleUnshift<any, Tuple> ? 
TupleUnshift<any, TupleUnshift<any, Tuple>>['length'] :
Increment<T, TupleUnshift<any, TupleUnshift<any, Tuple>>>
```

In the end it should work like:

```
type five = 5
type six = Increment<five> // 6
```

P.S. `TupleUnshift` is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53985533/9259778).

Comment: I answered the other question... I think adding in a helper tuple doesn't really do you any good here, or at least I can't see it.

Comment: Do you mean by helper tuple this: `[any]`? It is a tuple with `length` `1`, so that when I unshift `any` to it, it becomes a tuple with length `2`

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Maybe I don't understand.  What should, say, `Increment<10, ["a","b"]>` become?

Comment: @jcalz Ahh, the second type param is only for recursive purposes. Normally it is supposed to be like this `Increment<3> //4`. Sorry I had a mistake, fixed it I guess, so now it should be more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### UPDATE FOR TS4.1+

Welcome back!  TypeScript 4.1 introduced [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types), which, along with things like [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) has made it possible to perform a "add one to a non-negative whole number" via recursion.  It actually behaves pretty well but **I still do not recommend it for production environments** for reasons I'll get into shortly.

---

First of all, I will <strike>shamelessly copy</strike> borrow a technique from [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26223#issuecomment-674514787) by [@lazytype](https://github.com/lazytype) in microsoft/TypeScript#26223 which makes a tuple of any non-negative integer length without smashing into the recursion limit at about depth 23.  It does this by breaking the integer into a sum of distinct powers of two (i.e., using its binary representation) and concatenating tuples of these lengths.  Variadic tuple types make it easy enough to double the length of a tuple (`[...T, ...T]`) so this technique supports tuples of lengths well into the thousands and tens of thousands:

```
type BuildPowersOf2LengthArrays<N extends number, R extends never[][]> =
  R[0][N] extends never ? R : BuildPowersOf2LengthArrays<N, [[...R[0], ...R[0]], ...R]>;

type ConcatLargestUntilDone<N extends number, R extends never[][], B extends never[]> =
  B["length"] extends N ? B : [...R[0], ...B][N] extends never
  ? ConcatLargestUntilDone<N, R extends [R[0], ...infer U] ? U extends never[][] ? U : never : never, B>
  : ConcatLargestUntilDone<N, R extends [R[0], ...infer U] ? U extends never[][] ? U : never : never, [...R[0], ...B]>;

type Replace<R extends any[], T> = { [K in keyof R]: T }

type TupleOf<T, N extends number> = number extends N ? T[] : {
  [K in N]:
  BuildPowersOf2LengthArrays<K, [[never]]> extends infer U ? U extends never[][]
  ? Replace<ConcatLargestUntilDone<K, U, []>, T> : never : never;
}[N]
```

Then the `Increment` type you want is just this:

```
type Increment<N extends number> = [0, ...TupleOf<0, N>]['length'];
```

which creates a tuple of length `N` filled with zeros (doesn't matter what you use there), prepends a single `0` to it, and gets its length.

Let's see it in action:

```
type Seven = Increment<6>; // 7
type Sixteen = Increment<15>; // 16
type OneHundredOne = Increment<100>; // 101
type OneThousand = Increment<999>;  // 1000
type SixOrElevent = Increment<5 | 10>; // 6 | 11
type Numbah = Increment<number>; // number
```

Nice! That looks like what we want, I think.  Now for the not-nice part and the reason I don't recommend it:

```
// Don't do this
type Kablooey = Increment<3.14> // Loading...
```

That will cause the compiler to have a heart attack; the recursive tuple-builder never reaches its goal because no matter how big of a tuple it makes, there's never an element at index `3.14`.

---

Can that be fixed? Sure.  We can add an extra guard into the `TupleOf` type to bail out if there's a decimal point in the string representation of the number (shout-out to [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types)!):

```
type TupleOf<T, N extends number> = number extends N ? T[] :
  `${N}` extends `${infer X}.${infer Y}` ? T[] : {
    [K in N]:
    BuildPowersOf2LengthArrays<K, [[never]]> extends infer U ? U extends never[][]
    ? Replace<ConcatLargestUntilDone<K, U, []>, T> : never : never;
  }[N]
```

Now `3.14` results in `number`, which is not `4.14`, but is at least reasonable and not compiler-explodey:

```
type AlsoNumber = Increment<3.14> // number
```

---

So there you go; it works and performs well.

I still can't bring myself to tell anyone "please use this in your production environment", though.  It's just too potentially fragile.  How sure are you, looking at the byzantine type munging above, that there isn't some simple edge case that will crash your compiler?  Do you want to be responsible for patching such things just to get the compiler to add one to a number?

Instead I'd still recommend a simple lookup until and unless TypeScript implements arithmetic on numeric literals as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#15645](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15645) and/or [microsoft/TypeScript#26382](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/26382).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAsBdIBwZwFwgOYEtLgK4CMB0BjAewFthjV8AnQuQgM0mABUBPGAUwGUrUZHU4cTOzjAATADYxYgMwBiAUPZFixdgDtIAWgkB2ACwBWAIz7dADl0AoK5DbtQAIUyoANgBMACoQDu7SnAA8nRiADIayBgAgpSUAIYscAA8AHKg7AAekBrucKDqmMTY-gA0oABK6Vk5eersAG7+ANoAuq0AfKAAvFagFU0ADG0pLVXZ6rn5Df6gAPwVoAhOLh7efgHBYRHRsQnJKWVNTbgn5YMtZSe4Z0MXoFflLe0A3DZ2HKAAwoTq+HGQoTilGQIkgAFVNG4ACI-dipMY1fKFYqUMqVTLjSZ1RqUVqtMqOBETWrTXFPbq9JxNABErm24GpowxiLS80JS2Op3OlxOjmGTOqxKmOMp82+v3+gOBoIhkGhsNSaKJkyaNzuV1Q6joMzBo3mYOVJJxeL1oANS2xMwtpIJ7UpS3FfwBQJBcHBkNcMLqioWzKFqu59xOmu1lDNpoNfqxpJNczNi2FVsTqNAnOugaufJeb3sFXYMFccXwcPRgsmcXULHxoCYnS6oAA3qmANKgTWgADW7BY9AqLSWTFAAF8cx8mJgC+xgkkmGU0lHasj-HWkUUZgvQKya61FpSAAYAEgbKSHe8NoEPDZDMwAGkPcEfr2GAJqnuNMHdLBuUvpNVvtkYEB-ZY3C8Xx-CCEJwnUSJwBieJEiSZtDiaS1KBackNyfeN9XPNCTWA+ZynzQtiySR1JRdGUPS9OFkLNQ4njKWsEzQ1jSVePohyaEZRwcABJX5KHYNRNHhDcCjXSgV0GHlcHHSdpwGOd2jaAByOkYIwNSWleWxc04aZ1G6UBBKoESNEgJIBheUAQFAax3gcThUGqDQTLM4TRKs4xDFs+zjAkfSPkCOoAAlMAmYT3FChx608iyxOMAYbOeOywGS4xgocWKmHAQhMDgCt3A8oTEqsgBOKrbPS0BkpS7LQBcjJAkoABROlGk0UrzO8pJDFAAAfOrUtqiQhrqrKnM3ZE4nAHqvMspJJJRfywBW-xGqiVxaBSJcw3isq+pkXBTE6eyNsoKwgA)

---

---

#### PREVIOUS ANSWER FOR EARLIER TS VERSIONS:

I think in the other question and in comments I said that you can *try* to do this recursively but that the compiler, even if you can make it happy with the definition, will give up at some relatively shallow depth.  Let's look at it here:

```
interface Reduction<Base, In> {
  0: Base
  1: In
}
type Reduce<T, R extends Reduction<any, any>, Base =[]> =
  R[[T] extends [Base] ? 0 : 1]

type Cons<H, T extends any[]> = ((h: H, ...t: T) => void) extends
  ((...c: infer C) => void) ? C : never;

interface TupleOfIncrementedLength<N extends number, Tuple extends any[]=[]>
  extends Reduction<Tuple, Reduce<Tuple['length'],
    TupleOfIncrementedLength<N, Cons<any, Tuple>>, N
  >> { }

type Increment<N extends number> = TupleOfIncrementedLength<N>[1] extends
  { length: infer M } ? M : never;
```

---

EDIT: You asked for an explanation, so here it is:

First, the definition of `Cons<H, T>` uses [tuples in rest/spread positions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) and [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to take a head type `H` and a tuple tail type `T` and return a new tuple in which the head has been prepended to the tail. (The name ["cons"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cons#Lists) comes from list manipulation in Lisp and later in Haskell.)  So `Cons<"a", ["b","c"]>` evaluates to `["a","b","c"]`.

As background, TypeScript generally tries to stop you from doing circular types.  You can sneak around the back door by using some [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to defer some execution, like this:

```
type RecursiveThing<T> = 
  { 0: BaseCase, 1: RecursiveThing<...T...> }[Test<...T...> extends BaseCaseTest ? 0 : 1]
```

This should either evaluate to `BaseCase` or `RecursiveThing<...T...>`, but the conditional type inside the index access gets deferred, and so the compiler doesn't realize that it will end up being a circular reference.  Unfortunately this has the *very bad* side effect of causing the compiler to bottom out on infinite types and often getting bogged down when you start using these things in practice.  For example, you can define `TupleOfIncrementedLength<>` like this:

```
type TupleOfIncrementedLength<N extends number, Tuple extends any[]=[]> = {
  0: Cons<any, Tuple>,
  1: TupleOfIncrementedLength<N, Cons<any, Tuple>>
}[Tuple['length'] extends N ? 0 : 1]
```

and it works, even for `N` up to 40 or 50 or so.  But if you stick this in a library and start using it you might find that your compile time becomes very high and even causes compiler crashes.  It's not consistent, so I can't easily generate an example here, but it's bitten me enough for me to avoid it.  It's possible this problem will eventually be fixed.  But for now, I'd follow the [advice](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897#issuecomment-401418254) of [@ahejlsberg](https://github.com/ahejlsberg) (lead architect for TypeScript):

> It's clever, but it definitely pushes things well beyond their intended use. While it may work for small examples, it will scale horribly. Resolving those deeply recursive types consumes a lot of time and resources and might in the future run afoul of the recursion governors we have in the checker.
>
> Don't do it!

Enter [@strax](https://github.com/strax), who [discovered](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25947#issuecomment-446916897) that since `interface` declarations are not evaluated eagerly the way that `type` declarations are (since `type`s are just aliases, the compiler tries to evaluate them away), if you can extend an `interface` in the right way, in conjunction with the conditional type trick above, the compiler should not get bogged down.  My experiments confirm this, but I'm still not convinced... there could be a counterexample that only shows up when you try to compose these things.

Anyway, the above `TupleOfIncrementedLength` type with `Reduction` and `Reduce` works much the same way as the "naïve" version from before, except that it is an `interface`.  I really can't pick it apart without writing ten pages and I don't feel like doing it, sorry.  The actual output is a `Reduction` whose `1` property has the tuple we care about.

After that, `Increment` is defined in terms of `TupleOfIncrementedLength` by getting the `1` property and extracting its `length` (I don't use plain indexed access because the compiler can't deduce that `TupleOfIncrementedLength<N>[1]` is an array type.  Luckily conditional type inference saves us).

---

<strike>I don't know that it's too useful for me to walk through exactly how this works.</strike>  Suffice it to say that it keeps increasing the length of a tuple until its length is one greater than the `N` parameter, and then returns the length of that tuple.  And it does work, for small `N`:

```
type Seven = Increment<6>; // 7
type Sixteen = Increment<15>; // 16
```

But, on my compiler at least (version 3.3.0-dev.20190117), this happens:

```
type TwentyThree = Increment<22>; // 23
type TwentyWhaaaa = Increment<23>; // {} 
type Whaaaaaaaaaa = Increment<100>; // {}
```

Also, you get some weirdness with unions and `number`:

```
type WhatDoYouThink = Increment<5 | 10>; // 6 
type AndThis = Increment<number>; // 1
```

You can probably fix both of these behaviors with [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types), but this feels like you're bailing out a sinking ship.

If the above super-complicated and fragile method gives out entirely at 23, you might as well use a hardcoded list of outputs as I showed in [the answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54243723/2887218).  For anyone playing along at home who wants to see answers in one place, it is:

```
type Increment<N extends number> = [
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,
  21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,
  38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54, // as far as you need
  ...number[] // bail out with number
][N]
```

That is comparatively simpler, and works for higher numbers:

```
type Seven = Increment<6>; // 7
type Sixteen = Increment<15>; // 16
type TwentyThree = Increment<22>; // 23
type TwentyFour = Increment<23>; // 24
type FiftyFour = Increment<53>; // 54
```

is generally more graceful when it fails, and fails at a known place:

```
type NotFiftyFiveButNumber = Increment<54>; // number
type NotOneHundredOneButNumber = Increment<100>; // number
```

and naturally does better things in the "weird" cases above

```
type WhatDoYouThink = Increment<5 | 10>; // 6 | 11 
type AndThis = Increment<number>; // number
```

So, all in all, recursive types are more trouble than they're worth here, in my opinion.

Okay, hope that helps again.  Good luck!

Comment: That's **awesome**! I mean, even if you figured out that the compiler's limit on recursion is 22 or so, the important thing is that it has been figured out! But I am also having hard time to see how you achieved the recursion. Remember this question is more about it, than about incrementation? Can you please add more info on how you've achieved it? I've been trying to understand it myself for 30 minutes already and I will have, but maybe it will be also usefull for others wondering. Again, giant thanks to you, sir!

Comment: OMG, thank you so much, again! :-) That's GREAT explanation. I have no better word for my lack of English knowledge.